# Hololens2 overheating applications

Tags: hololens, mrtk

when I use MsStore's some applications(ex. HoloAnatomy Demo) more than 30 minuts, my hololens2  is so heated that it is shutdowned. Is it normal? Can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you operate HoloLens at +50ºF (+10ºC) to +80ºF (+27ºC), you can check more detail on temperature range from [Temperature and regulatory information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-environment-considerations#temperature-and-regulatory-information), here is a quote to the guidelines:

> 1. Store device in an environment within temperature range (either in Standby or Off) for an hour before using the device.
> 2. Use device in an environment within temperature range.
> 3. Use device indoors.
> 4. Use device in shade; even indoors avoid direct sunlight though windows or skylights.
> 5. If you follow the above guidelines but experience unexpected overheating issues, ensure Full telemetry is enabled before submitting [Feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-feedback).